# Godel's proof for dummies

Tags: foundations, incompleteness

Can someone give me as simple-a-proof as possible for Godel's Incompleteness Theorem?

I'd love to understand it more.

Comment: Some of the answers, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/453589/120540) (the linked chapter, starting at the bottom of page 3) to a related question may be useful. I just browsed highly-voted posts in the [tag:incompleteness] tag.

Comment: This takes a book, not a few paragraphs.  I recommend Nagel and Newman as an intro, though others have other views.

Comment: See [Proof sketch for Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_sketch_for_G%C3%B6del%27s_first_incompleteness_theorem) and more specifically (see *Refernces*): George Boolos, "A New Proof of the Gödel Incompleteness Theorem" (1998) in G.Boolos, [Logic, Logic, and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=2BvlvetSrlgC&pg=PR6), page 383-on.

Answer (score 1):

I try to keep it very short - for more I also highly recommend Nagel-Newman's book *Goedel's Theorem*.

There are two two main observations:

1. A sufficiently rich formal system $\mathscr T$ can make statements about itself: there is a computable translation of meta-theoretic/natural language statements $\phi$ *about* $\mathscr T$ (e.g., some formula in $\mathscr T$ is provable, $\mathscr T$ is consistent, ...)  into formulas $\lceil\phi\rceil$  in $\mathscr T$. The translation is sound in the sense that whenever $\phi$ holds in the meta-theory, then $\lceil\phi\rceil$ is provable within $\mathscr T$.

   *In particular*, given any formula $\psi$ of $\mathscr T$ you get, in a 'computable' way (this e.g. would need to be made more precise), another formula $\lceil\psi\text{ is not provable in }{\mathscr T}\rceil$, expressing that $\psi$ is not provable in $\mathscr T$.

   *How:* Encode meta-theoretic objects like formulas, proofs, ... by natural numbers via *Goedel numberings*.
2. *Very roughly* any suitably computable operation $\textbf O$ on $\mathscr T$-formulas has a *fixed point*, i.e. a formula $\psi$ of $\mathscr T$ such that ${\textbf O}(\psi)$ and $\psi$ are equivalent.

   *How:* One realizes that the self-interpretability of $\mathscr T$ gives rise to an (at least informal) interpretation of $\lambda$-calculus, and one imitates a fixed point combinator from $\lambda$-calculus to get the desired fixed points. See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27322/fixed-points-in-computability-and-logic

**Given these two observations**, you get Goedel's theorem as follows: first, choose a fixed point of $$\psi\mapsto \lceil\psi\text{ is not provable in }{\mathscr T}\rceil.$$ In words, $\psi$ is equivalent to the formalization (within $\mathscr T$) of the statement that $\psi$ is not provable; this is what corresponds to the formalization of *I am not provable* which you often find in  introductions to Goedel's theorem.

Now, suppose $\psi$ can be proved from $\mathscr T$. Then, the soundness of translation says that also $$\lceil\psi\text{ is provable in }{\mathscr T}\rceil,\quad\text{ or equivalently }\quad\neg \lceil\psi\text{ is not provable in }{\mathscr T}\rceil$$ can be proved from $\mathscr T$. However, by construction, the provability of the latter is equivalent to provability of $\neg\psi$ by our choice of $\psi$. Hence, if $\psi$ is provable, then also $\neg\psi$, hence $\mathscr T$ is inconsistent. So we arrive at:

**Conclusion:** If $\mathscr T$ is consistent, then $\psi$ (from above) is not provable.

On the other hand, the translation of the right hand side into $\mathscr T$ is again equivalent to $\psi$, so we finally obtain:

**Theorem:** If $\mathscr T$ is consistent, then there is a *true* formula $\psi$ in $\mathscr T$ (*true* in the sense that it is the translation of a true statement in the meta-theory) which is not provable from $\mathscr T$.